# confused with friend function

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, friend

Inside FileTwo.h

```
#ifndef FILETWO
#define FILETWO
#include"FileOne.h"
class FileOne ;
class FileTwo
{
public:
    int Test(FileOne One){
        return (One.var1+One.var2);}

    FileTwo(void);
    ~FileTwo(void);
};
#endif
```

Inside FileOne.h

```
#ifndef FILEONE
#define FILEONE
#include"FileTwo.h"
class FileTwo ;
class FileOne
{
private:
     int var1 , var2 , var3 ;
public :
    friend int FileTwo::Test(FileOne One);
    FileOne(){
        var1= 12;var2 = 24;
    }

};
#endif
```

Inside main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std ;
#include"FileOne.h"
#include"FileTwo.h"

int main(){
FileOne one ;
FileTo two ;
cout<<two.Test(one);
}
```

During compilation i got the following error

```
   1-- error C2027: use of undefined type 'FileOne' c:\users\e543925\documents\visual studio 2005\projects\myproject\filetwo.h
   2--error C2027: use of undefined type 'FileOne'  c:\users\e543925\documents\visual studio 2005\projects\myproject\filetwo.h  

   3--error C2228: left of '.var1' must have class/struct/union c:\users\e543925\documents\visual studio 2005\projects\myproject\filetwo.h
   4--error C2228: left of '.var2' must have class/struct/union c:\users\e543925\documents\visual studio 2005\projects\myproject\filetwo.h
```

I have found one workaround like definning the Test function inside FileTwo.cpp . But i want to know how the above issue can be resolved inside header file .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is that you are including both files in each other. When your compiler goes to parse `FileOne.h`, it includes `FileTwo.h`, so it reads that, skips `FileOne.h` (thanks to the include guards; otherwise, you would go into an infinite loop) and tries to use class `FileOne`, which is not yet defined.

In practice, this is just as if you had not included `FileOne.h` in `FileTwo.h`; you cannot call methods on `One` because its type (`FileOne`) is not yet defined. Nothing to do with friend classes. Or not yet (you will get into this problem later).

From your code, it looks like you want to use class `FileTwo` to test `FileOne`. In this case, `FileOne` does not really need to know much about `FileTwo`, just allow it to look at its innards (aka make it a friend). So your code can boil down to:

FileOne.h:

```
#ifndef FILEONE
#define FILEONE
class FileOne
{
  friend class FileTwo; // This is all FileOne needs from FileTwo
private:
  int var1 , var2 , var3 ;
public :
  FileOne(){
    var1= 12;var2 = 24;
  }
};
#endif
```

FileTwo.h:

```
#ifndef FILETWO
#define FILETWO
#include"FileOne.h"
class FileTwo
{
public:
  int Test(FileOne One) {
    return (One.var1+One.var2);
  }

  FileTwo();
  ~FileTwo();
};
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to include `FileOne.h` inside `FileTwo.h`, at least in this simple example. But in general, a circular include implies there is something wrong with your design.

You'll have to make the whole class a friend, not just a single method. I'd reconsider this friendship as well, since this introduces major coupling between the classes. Can you not accomplish the same with public methods?

Comment: I can do the same with public method too . But i was learning some concept on friend and stuck in to this .
I removed #include "FileOne.h" from FileTwo.h .But it still giving me the same error .

Comment: @Learner, ok. Your problems should be resolved once the entire class is a friend, and there is no circular include. This is a scope issue. Bear my advice, in mind, though.

Comment: @Learner In fact, it is the other way around. You don't need to include `FileTwo.h` in `FileOne.h`. Try it and then you will get into the friendship problem StoryTeller explains.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a circular dependency, which is solvable by using incomplete type declarations. As it stands, your code requires complete type declaration in both files:

1) in FileOne.h: `friend int FileTwo::Test(FileOne One);` (you're asking the compiler to find a member function of `FileTwo`)

2) in FileTwo.h: `int Test(FileOne One){
        return (One.var1+One.var2);}` (you're asking the compiler to find some member variables of `FileOne`)

You have to use an incomplete type declaration in at least one of the files (`class FileOne;` `class FileTwo;`). You are already trying to do it, but using the `#include` directives undermines that. You have two options:

One is to make `FileTwo` a friend of `FileOne` as a whole class, as that is allowed by using an incomplete type. Remove `#include "FileTwo.h"`.

The other one you have already found by yourself:

> I have found one workaround like definning the Test function inside FileTwo.cpp.

Remove `#include "FileOne.h"` from FileTwo.h in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend declaration is fine, the issue you are having is `circular include`. You could break the circular include by putting one of class implementation into cpp file.

For example, break FileTwo class into FileTwo.h and FileTwo.cpp should fix your issue. Or, declare `friend FileTwo;` then one forward declaration is enough:

FileOne.h

```
#ifndef FILEONE
#define FILEONE

class FileTwo;
class FileOne
{
private:
     int var1 , var2 , var3 ;
public :
    friend FileTwo;
    FileOne(){
        var1= 12;var2 = 24;
    }

};
#endif
```

FileTwo.h

```
#ifndef FILETWO
#define FILETWO

#include "FileOne.h"
class FileTwo
{
public:
   inline int Test(FileOne One)
    {
      return (One.var1+One.var2);
    }

    FileTwo(void){}
    ~FileTwo(void){}
};
#endif
```

Comment: This is the same thing i have said in my post . To get rid of this i can define the same in cpp file  but i want to do it in header . can you please give some solution to resolve the circular include ?

Comment: break FileTwo into two files is the normal way of breaking `circular include`. If you really need to use `friend int FileTwo::Test(FileOne One);`, I can't find a better way.

Comment: Thanks . i got it . If i have to do it inside header files then friend class is the only way ..

Comment: the other way is to use template but it's a bit more complicated.